# Change QUERYSTRING with the lighttpd proxy

Tags: proxy, lighttpd

First of all sorry for my English, hope you can undestand it.

I need to change the URL of the destination server with Lighttpd, I mean, someone is going to write an URL like http://my.proxy.server.com/MYQUERY and I need to change it to something like http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/search?q=MYQUERY.

I tried to add an "querystring" option like the configuration below  but it didn't work.

```
proxy.server     = (

                    "" =>
                 (
                   ( "host" => "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
                     "port" => 80,
                     "querystring" => "/search?q=$HTTP[querystring]"
                   )
                 )
                )
```

I also tried to force changing the URL with the code below but it didn't work neither.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/"{
server.querystring = "/search/q=$HTTP[querystring]"
}
```

What can I do? Does lighttpd have this feature?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. First of all I need to have the mod_rewrite activated, then before the proxy configuration I just need to rewrite the url, like:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "/(.*)" => "/search?q=$1" )
```

Thank you all.