# lighttpd reverse proxy to apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, lighttpd

I have just started using lighttpd and I am trying to configure it to act as a reverse proxy to an Apache server running on 127.0.0.1 on port 8080. I have multiple wordpress blogs running on the same host

```
127.0.0.1:8080/blog1
127.0.0.1:8080/blog2
```

I have just bought a domain name www.mydomain.com and I would like to requests to blog1 to appear like this

`www.mydomain.com/article1` even though on my server this translates to `127.0.0.1:8080/blog1/article1`

What I am after is an example of lighttpd.conf configuration that will redirect requests from `www.mydomain.com` that arrive on port 80 to be redirected to `127.0.0.1:8080/blog1`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457727/change-querystring-with-the-lighttpd-proxy) will probably be helpful. You're going to need to do a [rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite) to have the `/blog1/article1` instead of just `/article1`, then you'll need to do the proxy. ([mod_proxy docs](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxy)). I would test getting the proxy working first, then get the rewrite to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.46 (released in 2017) has `proxy.header` which allows limited rewriting of the url prefix when proxying.  See [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModProxy)